# Django model filtering(query)

Tags: django, templates, filter, model

I'm struggling with a model filtering, what I doing wrong? Here is my code:

**models.py**

```
class Images(models.Model):
    TAK_NIE = (
        ('y', 'Tak'),
        ('n', 'Nie')
    )
    nazwa_polska = models.ForeignKey(Roslina, related_name='images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(max_length=255, upload_to=generate_filename)
    zdjecie_glowne = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=TAK_NIE,default='n')
    def czyGlowne(self):
        return self.filter(zdjecie_glowne='y')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nazwa_polska.nazwa_polska
```

**html not working:**

```
{% for zdjecie in ros.images.czyGlowne %}
   {{ zdjecie.image }}
   <img src="{% static '' %}{{ zdjecie.image|cut:"static/"}}" alt="brak 
   zdjecia" class="img-thumbnail zdjecia">
{% endfor %}
```

on the same page working html code:

```
{% for zdjecie in ros.images.all %}
    <div class="col-lg-4">
       <img src="{% static '' %}{{ zdjecie.image|cut:"static/"}}" alt="brak 
       zdjecia" class="img-thumbnail zdjecia">
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: post your view, the filter should be there

Comment: What is 'ros' as being passed in to the template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view should be filtering or creating the filtered queryset.

You can also filter like this:

```
{% for zdjecie in ros.images.all %}
(% if zdjecie.zdjecie_glowne == 'y' %}
   {{ zdjecie.image }}
   <img src="{% static '' %}{{ zdjecie.image|cut:"static/"}}" alt="brak 
   zdjecia" class="img-thumbnail zdjecia">
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```